# Server-Client connection in GameKit

Tags: ios, client-server, p2p, gamekit

GKTank provided by apple restricted to use bluetooth to establish a connection. As I know, peer to peer connection using GameKit the maximum player is 4 and 16 for server-client connection.

I'm confusing about how it operates a server-client connection.

I want to connect maximum 16 players in a same local wifi network. Is it possible to do that using just GameKit (not GameCenter)? Is there any sample project demonstrate how it works?

Thank you

Comment: did you find out the way to Client-server connection using wifi even i am facing the same problem....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think it is possible, as documentation for Game Kit Programming Guide (Peer-to-Peer connectivity section) says:

`The maximum size of a client-server game is 16 players.`

Your biggest problem will be how to make all the players connect together (i would go for PeerPicker - dont use your own user interface version because its very painful to implement it properly, especially for so many players)

Another problem you may experience is that bluetooth may not be able to send and receive data fast enough in case of 16 players (i think 16 players is the case for turn-based games)

Have fun ;)